# Read CSV file Include Strings With Comma

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

I have a csv file that has many string file to this format : for example "1,125"
when I read Csv These strings are empty.

```
string header = isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";
string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]";
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
              @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
              ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
{
     DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
     dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
     adapter.Fill(dataTable);
}
```

my CSV file is like this:

---

ABS,15,1392/12/12,501,"1,205",KTI1212,"123,5",KK

Comment: probably you should add schema.ini file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why don't you just use System.IO, open the document and then parse through the file with a delimiter of ','. Seems like it would be much easier and faster in the application. Let me know if you need some code, but simple goggling gave me some code. Not the best, but it'll do the job: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/794dce27-0c29-48ca-8ddb-bc596cd623d4/read-and-parse-a-csv-file?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: in my opinion better solution for reading CSV files is CSV Reader: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Comment: @KarolMarianSłuszniak I was going to mention it. Excellent library, I have to say!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code:

```
try
{
    //Read the file
    System.IO.StreamReader f = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    string line = f.ReadLine();

    //Split text by comma
    string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
    int tokenCount = tokens.Length;

    //Reconstruct the broken strings - tokensList retreives the final values
    System.Collections.ArrayList tokensList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

    string token = "";
    bool stringFound = false;
    string currentToken;
    for (int i=0; i<tokenCount; i++)
    {
        currentToken = tokens[i];
        if (!stringFound)
        {   
            //Check if not a string
            if ((currentToken.Trim().StartsWith("\"") && !currentToken.Trim().EndsWith("\"")) || currentToken.Trim().Equals("\""))
            {
                stringFound = true;
                token = currentToken;
            }
            else
            {
                //Add the string as final value
                tokensList.Add(currentToken);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Reconstruct the string
            token += "," + currentToken;
            if (currentToken.Trim().EndsWith("\""))
            {
                int quoteIndex = currentToken.LastIndexOf("\"");
                if (quoteIndex == 0 || (quoteIndex > 0 && currentToken[quoteIndex-1] != '"'))
                {
                    tokensList.Add(token);
                    stringFound = false;
                    token = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
}
```